# Change column refence id by his name keeping NULL values

Tags: mysql, sql, database, reference, null

I have two tables. Table 1:

```
+-------+----------+---------+---------+
| ID    | name     |   refT1 |  refT2  |
+-------+----------+---------+---------+
| 1     |  Name1   |   1     |    2    |
| 2     |  Name2   |   2     |    4    |
| 3     |  Name3   |  NULL   |   NULL  |
| 4     |  Name4   |   3     |   NULL  |
+-------+----------+---------+---------+
```

and Table 2:

```
+-------+--------+
| ID    |  name  |
+-------+--------+
| 1     |   A1   |
| 2     |   A2   |
| 3     |   A3   |
| 4     |   A4   |
+-------+--------+
```

I need this table

```
+-------+----------+---------+---------+
| ID    | name     |   A1    |    A1   |
+-------+----------+---------+---------+
| 1     |  Name1   |   A1    |    A2   |
| 2     |  Name2   |   A2    |    A4   |
| 3     |  Name3   |  NULL   |   NULL  |
| 4     |  Name4   |   A3    |   NULL  |
+-------+----------+---------+---------+
```

I wrote a sql command, but the rows that have null value disappear and I want to keep them.

Comment: You can't have the column name A1 twice in the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do `LEFT JOIN` twice:

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t2.name as a1, t3.name as a2
from table1 t1
  left join table2 as t2 on t1.refT1 = t2.id
  left join table2 as t3 on t1.refT2 = t3.id
```

(Left join is to include those disappeared "null rows")

Answer (score 2):

Hope this query will help you:

```
SELECT ID, name,
Case when Table_1.refT1 is null then NULL else Table_2.name end as A1,
Case when Table_1.refT2 is null then NULL else Table_2.name end as A2
 from 
Table_1
inner join
Table_2
on Table_1.ID = Table_2.ID
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5d8f2/1)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but there is an error on Table_1.ID = Table_2.ID. I knew http://jsfiddle.net but not http://sqlfiddle.com/. Good tool